# An annotation to indicate that a method throws no exception in Kotlin

Tags: exception, kotlin, annotations

Since Kotlin has no checked exceptions, whether a function throws an exception is unknown. When a function throws an exception, I can use the `@Throws` annotation to indicate what exceptions are thrown. On the other hand, what annotation can I use to indicate that in a function all exceptions are handled and no is thrown, for better readability?

Comment: @Throws provides compile time structure for java that is calling kotlin code. For java calling kotlin code that does not throw exceptions, the absence of this annotation is enough. If you are looking purely for a visual aid, you can make your own annotation and make it do nothing.

Comment: @Laurence Do you think `@Throws(Nothing::class)` can be a good "visual aid"?

Comment: I assume you are adding the other annotations for java interoperability? If so, all of that java will be expecting a "Nothing" exception and you will have to write try catch blocks for it. I would suggest make your own annotation like "@ThrowsNothing" or if you do not need this for java interoperability then adopt the kotlin mindset of No Checked exceptions. See here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html